# swap image with fadein on mouseover/fadeout on mouse out

Tags: jquery, mouseover, fadein, fade, fadeout

the title say's it all...
i have made this tutorial [creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect](http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/)

but I want to apply 3 times in the same ... with diferent images, and when I try to do, he gets all uncoordinated and 2nd over image goes to the first place ...

```
 <div class="AccordionPanelTab"><img src="images/tab_19.jpg" width="960" height="144" alt="zipperLogo" class="a" /><img src="images/main_over_06.jpg" width="959" height="144" alt="zipperHover" /></div>
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: i want to apply the same effect on 3 diferent images!

Comment: Well, you only show two images in your script

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EQmhT/

Comment: im using the spry accordion

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Here you go

Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/6y8cA/3/)

```
$(".fadehover").on({

    mouseenter: function() {

        $(this).find('img').eq(0).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");

    },

    mouseleave: function() {

        $(this).find('img').eq(1).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");

    }

});
```

Comment: when i've got the mouseover i want the image fade and stop, and then fade out when the mouseout

Comment: @VítorCabral You mean the first image fade out on mouseover, then the second image fade out on mouseout?